# Consumer not pulling Kafka message

Tags: c#, go, confluent-platform

We have some micro-services developed in c# and go languages. we use confluent-kafka for messaging and facing a problem: Go services are able to consume messages published from all other services (be it from go or c#/.net micro service). But .net microservices are not getting messages published from go microservice but from .net microservices.

We are on windows platform and using confluent-kafka as kafka server and .net clients. In go we are using kafka-go library (https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go)

Note: in go we the kafka-go library allows to publish the message as byte-array. whereas in .net we are publishing a message as plain-text. I am not sure if it is a problem for .net services to consume messages published from go-services as byte-array.
I can see messages published from go-services in kafka-tool 2.0.

Expected behavior will be .net services are able to pull/consume messages published from go-micro-services.

Comment: What does your code look like? What errors do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause and resolved. The problem was there is no key-deserializer set in dot net services and dotnet publishers didn't set the key of kafka message but go publishers were setting the key. as there is no key deserializer set in .net, they were getting ConsumerError. Now key deserializer set to .net consumer and the issue perished.